# Text overflow on review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

I just saw a question which overflows the side under the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

I don't think this is intended, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your input. This queue no longer exists, but I released a fix for a similar issue that affected *all* queues 4-6 weeks ago. That fix prevents posts that display in any review queue from overflowing their container.

Comment: Fix for what? 10k flag queue is long gone... (link now redirects to review)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The general ability for text to overflow any of the review queue displays.

Comment: Well, that's essentially whole different thing then, changed the report to fit the fix. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard fair enough, done.